# Why neither app.exec_() nor app.exec() work in the script in Python?

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.10

I work in python 3.10, PyQt5. I have created a script. At run it gives the following error:
'QApplication' object has no attribute exec_().
Here is my script:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import design # This is my converted design file
class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  
        self.btnBrowse.clicked.connect(self.browse_folder)                                                  
    def browse_folder(self):
        self.listWidget.clear()
        directory = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select directory")
        if directory: 
            for file_name in os.listdir(directory): 
                self.listWidget.addItem(file_name)  
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()   
    app.exec_() 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

type here
```

What to do?

I have changed app.exec_() to app.exec(). But no result.
Though PyQt5 supports both app.exec_() and app.exec().

Comment: That's what the IDE says or Python is throwing the exception. If it is the first then ignore it (false positive), if it is the second then show the full error message.

Comment: This is error in the window of IDLE. But application window opens and works normally. When exe file runs application and error windows open. If I close error window then application one closes too.

Comment: @Temur2 If you're using Python3, use `exec` rather than `exec_`.

Comment: I have fixed the error by myself. I retypied the variables app, exec_() and deleted the comments, the spaces after the operators. It worked. I didn't manage to define exact cause of the error.